# Бесконечный рендер в React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

стек: React, supabase.

Когда прокидываю пропс фильтр, то другой компоненте useEffect уходит в луп. Не могу разобраться почему.
Может у кого-то есть какие-то решения или замечания?

Логика: Resource...Tab.tsx (таблица) кликаем на строку (берется id).
Открывается следующая таблица (Resource...DataTable.tsx) применяется фильтр, который был создан в  Resource...Tab.tsx.

**Resource...Tab.tsx**

```
import { memo, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { MRT_ColumnDef, MRT_Row } from 'material-react-table';
import { ViewName } from 'supabase/Dataset';
import { Filter } from 'supabase/supabaseClient';
import { useModeContext, useTableContext } from 'pages/base/DetailPage/BaseDetailPageProvider';
import { getDictionaryPrefixCellFieldByNameAndReference } from 'supabase/tableCellUtils/getDictionaryPrefixCellField';
import { Wrapper } from 'components/Wrapper/Wrapper';
import { onChangeTableDataType } from 'supabase/generateColumnsFromType';
import { DetailPage_DataTable } from 'components/DataTable/DetailPage_DataTable';
import { ResourceUnit_Stage_DataTable } from './ResourceUnit_Stage_DataTable';

interface ResourceUnitTabType {
  childViewName: ViewName;
}
export const ResourceUnitTab = memo(({ childViewName }: ResourceUnitTabType) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [mode] = useModeContext();
  const [selectedResourceUnitId, setSelectedResourceUnitId] = useState(0);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<Filter[]>([]);
  const [showTabs, setShowTabs] = useState(false);
  const [data, setFields] = useTableContext(childViewName);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedResourceUnitId !== 0) {
      console.log('selectedResourceUnitId', selectedResourceUnitId);
      const newFilter: Filter = {
        column: 'parent_transportation_trip_resource_unit_id',
        operator: 'eq',
        value: selectedResourceUnitId,
      };
      console.log('newFilter', newFilter);
      setFilter([newFilter]);
    } else {
      setFilter([]); // Сбросьте фильтр, если выбранная запись равна 0
    }
  }, [selectedResourceUnitId]);

  const changeData: onChangeTableDataType = useCallback(
    (rowIndex, changedData) => {
      const copyData = { ...data };

      const state = copyData.rows[rowIndex]._state;

      copyData.rows[rowIndex] = {
        ...copyData.rows[rowIndex],
        ...changedData,
        _state: state !== 'Deleted' && state !== 'Inserted' ? 'Updated' : state,
      };

      setFields(copyData);
    },
    [data, setFields],
  );

  const handleClickRow = useCallback((row: MRT_Row) => {
    setSelectedResourceUnitId(Number(row.id));
    setShowTabs(true);
  }, []);

  const getDictField = useCallback(
    (fieldName: string, dictionary_view_name: ViewName) =>
      getDictionaryPrefixCellFieldByNameAndReference({
        fieldname: fieldName,
        dictionary_view_name,
        mode,
        onChangeTableData: changeData,
      }),
    [mode, changeData],
  );

  const columns: MRT_ColumnDef[] = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: '...',
        header: t('...') as string,
        Cell: getDictField('...', '...'),
        Edit: getDictField('...', '...'),
      },
    ],
    [t, getDictField],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <DetailPage_DataTable
          childViewName={childViewName as ViewName}
          predefinedColumns={columns}
          onClickRow={handleClickRow}
        />
      </Wrapper>
      {showTabs && (
        <ResourceUnit_Stage_DataTable childViewName="..." filter={filter} />
      )}
    </>
  );
});
```

**Resource...DataTable.tsx**

```
import { useMemo, useCallback, useState, useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { ViewName } from 'supabase/Dataset';
import { Filter } from 'supabase/supabaseClient';
import { getPrefixCellFieldByNameAndReference } from 'supabase/tableCellUtils/getDictionaryPrefixCellField';
import {
  useModeContext,
  useTableContext,
} from 'pages/base/DetailPage/BaseDetailPageProvider';
import { MRT_ColumnDef, MRT_Row } from 'material-react-table';
import { onChangeTableDataType } from 'supabase/generateColumnsFromType';
import { DetailPage_DataTable } from 'components/DataTable/DetailPage_DataTable';
import { StringField } from 'components/Field/StringField';
import { Wrapper } from 'components/Wrapper/Wrapper';
import { ResourceUnitTabs } from './ResourceUnitTabs';

export interface ResourceUnit_Stage_Interface {
  childViewName: ViewName;
  filter?: Filter[];
}

export const ResourceUnit_Stage_DataTable = memo(({
  childViewName, filter = []
}: ResourceUnit_Stage_Interface) => {
  console.log('STAGE_FILTER', filter);
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [mode] = useModeContext();
  const [data, setFields, getFilteredTable] = useTableContext(childViewName, filter);
  const [showTabs, setShowTabs] = useState(false);
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Примените фильтры при получении данных из другой view
    if (filter.length > 0) {
      /* Примените вашу логику фильтрации здесь с использованием фильтров */
      const filteredData = getFilteredTable();
      console.log('[filteredData]', filteredData);
      setFields(data);
    }
  }, [data, filter.length, getFilteredTable, setFields]);

  const onClickRow = useCallback((row: MRT_Row) => {
    setSelectedRow(Number(row.id));
    setShowTabs(true);
  }, []);

  const changeData: onChangeTableDataType = useCallback(
    (rowIndex, changedData) => {
      const copyData = { ...data };

      const state = copyData.rows[rowIndex]._state;

      copyData.rows[rowIndex] = {
        ...copyData.rows[rowIndex],
        ...changedData,
        _state: state !== 'Deleted' && state !== 'Inserted' ? 'Updated' : state,
      };

      setFields(copyData);
    },
    [data, setFields],
  );

  const StringRangeFieldRender = useCallback(
    (field: string, { row }: { row: Record<string, any> }) => {
      const fieldValue = data.rows[row.index]?.[field];
      const value = fieldValue || [null, null];
      return <StringField id={field} mode="view" value={value} withLabel={false} />;
    },
    [data],
  );

  const getRefence = useCallback(
    (fieldName: string, viewName: ViewName) =>
      getPrefixCellFieldByNameAndReference({
        fieldname: fieldName,
        mode,
        onChangeTableData: changeData,
        viewName,
      }),
    [mode, changeData],
  );

  const columns: MRT_ColumnDef[] = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: '...',
        header: t('...') as string,
        Cell: (row) => StringRangeFieldRender('...', row),
        Edit: (row) => StringRangeFieldRender('...', row),
      },
      {
        accessorKey: '...',
        header: t('...') as string,
        Cell: getRefence('...', '...'),
        Edit: getRefence('...', '...'),
      },
    ],
    [getRefence, t, StringRangeFieldRender],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <DetailPage_DataTable
          childViewName={childViewName as ViewName}
          predefinedColumns={columns}
          onChangeData={changeData}
          onClickRow={onClickRow}
        />
      </Wrapper>
      {/* {showTabs && (
        <Resource...Tabs
          selectedRow={selectedRow}
          positionChildViewName="..."
          stopChildViewName="..."
        />
      )} */}
    </>
  );
});
```

**Отрывок кастомного хука:**

```
export const useTableContext = (viewName: ViewOrTableName, filter?: Filter[]) => {
  const [dataset, setDataset] = useDataset();
  const tableIndex = dataset.tables.findIndex((table) => table.viewName === viewName);

  if (tableIndex < 0) {
    throw new Error(`Table for view ${String(viewName)} in dataset was not found`);
  }

  console.debug('newDataset.tables[tableIndex]: ', dataset.tables);
  const table = useMemo(() => dataset.tables[tableIndex], [dataset.tables, tableIndex]);

  // create setTable hook that uses setDataset and sets new table inside it

  const setTable = useCallback(
    (newTable: DatasetTable) => {
      const updatedTables = [...dataset.tables];
      updatedTables[tableIndex] = newTable;

      const updatedDataset = new Dataset(
        dataset.root_id,
        dataset.mode,
        updatedTables,
        dataset.tempCounter,
      );
      console.log('[updatedDataset]', updatedDataset);
      setDataset(updatedDataset);
    },
    [dataset, tableIndex, setDataset],
  );

  // create filteredTable function
  const getFilteredTable = useCallback(() => {
    if (filter && filter.length > 0) {
      // Filter the rows based on the provided filter conditions
      const filteredRows = table.rows.filter((row) =>
        filter.every((condition) => {
          const { column, operator, value } = condition;
          return row[column] === value;
        }));

      // Create a new DatasetTable with the filtered rows
      return {
        ...table,
        rows: filteredRows,
      };
    }
    // Return the original table if no filter is provided
    return table;
  }, [filter, table]);

  // return table, setTable, and getFilteredTable
  return [table, setTable, getFilteredTable] as const;
};
```

[image: Пример лупа]